# Case-insensitive search

Tags: javascript, search, string-comparison, case-insensitive

I'm trying to get a case-insensitive search with two strings in JavaScript working.

Normally it would be like this:

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var result= string.search(/best/i);
alert(result);
```

The `/i` flag would be for case-insensitive.

But I need to search for a second string; without the flag it works perfect:

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var searchstring="best";
var result= string.search(searchstring);
alert(result);
```

If I add the `/i` flag to the above example it would search for searchstring and not for what is in the variable "searchstring" (next example not working):

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var searchstring="best";
var result= string.search(/searchstring/i);
alert(result);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 397, accepted):

Yeah, use `.match`, rather than `.search`. The result from the `.match` call will return the actual string that was matched itself, but it can still be used as a boolean value.

```
var string = "Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var result = string.match(/best/i);
// result == 'BEST';

if (result){
    alert('Matched');
}
```

Using a regular expression like that is probably the tidiest and most obvious way to do that in JavaScript, but bear in mind it *is* a regular expression, and thus can contain regex metacharacters. If you want to take the string from elsewhere (eg, user input), or if you want to avoid having to escape a lot of metacharacters, then you're probably best using `indexOf` like this:

```
matchString = 'best';
// If the match string is coming from user input you could do
// matchString = userInput.toLowerCase() here.

if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf(matchString) != -1){
    alert('Matched');
}
```

Comment: Sorry how can you convert "best" into a variable in your first example? ```string.match(/best/i);```

Comment: Why would you use `.match` for boolean comparison. It searches beyond the first result. You need to stop after first match which `.test` or `.search` do. Check performance [here](https://jsperf.com/exec-vs-match-vs-test-vs-search/5).

Comment: `toLowerCase` will most likely fail the Turkey Test (http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) and similar case conversion issues. I'm not sure how `ReGex` handles it, but if I had to guess I'd say better.

Comment: @DougMolineux you can use the RegExp object constructor. 

`var text = "best"; var exp = new RegExp(test, "i");`. This is same as `/best/i`.

Answer (score 197):

Replace

```
var result= string.search(/searchstring/i);
```

with

```
var result= string.search(new RegExp(searchstring, "i"));
```

Comment: That's a rather messy way around it, as it takes to measures to guard against unexpected regexp metacharacters.

Comment: Dan, I doubt my answer deserves -1 from you. I tried helping ChrisBo by correcting his improper usage of JavaScript, namely: var result= string.search(/searchstring/i); to a proper one, where variable searchstring was used the way he intended.

Comment: Dan's right (though he probably meant to say "*no* measures"):  `s = 'a[b'; r = new RegExp(s)` results in a syntax error (unterminated character class)

Answer (score 41):

If you're just searching for a string rather than a more complicated regular expression, you can use `indexOf()` - but remember to lowercase both strings first because `indexOf()` is case sensitive:

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST"; 
var searchstring="best";

// lowercase both strings
var lcString=string.toLowerCase();
var lcSearchString=searchstring.toLowerCase();

var result = lcString.indexOf(lcSearchString)>=0;
alert(result);
```

Or in a single line:

```
var result = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchstring.toLowerCase())>=0;
```

Answer (score 27):

Suppose we want to find the string variable `needle` in the string variable `haystack`. There are three gotchas:

1. Internationalized applications should avoid `string.toUpperCase` and `string.toLowerCase`. Use a regular expression which ignores case instead. For example, `var needleRegExp = new RegExp(needle, "i");` followed by `needleRegExp.test(haystack)`.
2. In general, you might not know the value of `needle`. Be careful that `needle` does not contain any regular expression [special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions). Escape these using `needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");`.
3. In other cases, if you want to precisely match `needle` and `haystack`, just ignoring case, make sure to add `"^"` at the start and `"$"` at the end of your regular expression constructor.

Taking points (1) and (2) into consideration, an example would be:

```
var haystack = "A. BAIL. Of. Hay.";
var needle = "bail.";
var needleRegExp = new RegExp(needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i");
var result = needleRegExp.test(haystack);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

ES6+:

```
let string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
let searchstring="best";


let found = string.toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchstring.toLowerCase());
```

`includes()` returns `true` if `searchString` appears at one or more positions or `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the "unterminated character class" case, removing all non-alphanumeric chars would be helpful:

```
searchstring = searchstring.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @CHR15TO's answer, unlike other answers I've seen on other similar questions, that answer actually shows how to properly escape a user provided search string (rather than saying it would be necessary without showing how).

However, it's still quite clunky, and possibly relatively slower. So why not have a specific solution to what is likely a common requirement for coders? (And why not include it in the ES6 API BTW?)

My answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38290557/887092] on a similar question enables the following:

```
var haystack = 'A. BAIL. Of. Hay.';
var needle = 'bail.';
var index = haystack.naturalIndexOf(needle);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for case insensitive comparison:

1. Convert strings to upper case and then compare them using the strict operator (`===`).
2. Pattern matching using string methods:

   Use the "search" string method for case insensitive search.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    // 1st way

    var a = "apple";
    var b = "APPLE";
    if (a.toUpperCase() === b.toUpperCase()) {
      alert("equal");
    }

    //2nd way

    var a = " Null and void";
    document.write(a.search(/null/i));
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this **often** and use a simple 5 line prototype that accepts varargs.  It is **fast** and works **everywhere**.

```
myString.containsIgnoreCase('red','orange','yellow')
```

```js
/**
 * @param {...string} var_strings Strings to search for
 * @return {boolean} true if ANY of the arguments is contained in the string
 */
String.prototype.containsIgnoreCase = function(var_strings) {
  const thisLowerCase = this.toLowerCase()
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    let needle = arguments[i]
    if (thisLowerCase.indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

/**
 * @param {...string} var_strings Strings to search for
 * @return {boolean} true if ALL of the arguments are contained in the string
 */
String.prototype.containsAllIgnoreCase = function(var_strings) {
  const thisLowerCase = this.toLowerCase()
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    let needle = arguments[i]
    if (thisLowerCase.indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

// Unit test

let content = `
FIRST SECOND
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
FOO BAR
`

let data = [
  'foo',
  'Foo',
  'foobar',
  'barfoo',
  'first',
  'second'
]

let result
data.forEach(item => {
  console.log('Searching for', item)
  result = content.containsIgnoreCase(item)
  console.log(result ? 'Found' : 'Not Found')
})

console.log('Searching for', 'x, y, foo')
result = content.containsIgnoreCase('x', 'y', 'foo');
console.log(result ? 'Found' : 'Not Found')

console.log('Searching for all', 'foo, bar, foobar')
result = content.containsAllIgnoreCase('foo', 'bar', 'foobar');
console.log(result ? 'Found' : 'Not Found')

console.log('Searching for all', 'foo, bar')
result = content.containsAllIgnoreCase('foo', 'bar');
console.log(result ? 'Found' : 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make everything lowercase:

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var searchstring="best";
var result= (string.toLowerCase()).search((searchstring.toLowerCase()));
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for incase-sensitive string search and I tried

```
 var result = string.toLowerCase().match(searchstring)
```

and also

```
var result= string.search(new RegExp(searchstring, "i"));
```

But I did some little modifications and that worked for me

```
var result = string.match(new RegExp(searchstring, "i"));
```

This is will either lowercase, uppercase or combination also

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that if the user enters a string of text but leaves the input without selecting any of the autocomplete options no value is set in the hidden input, even if the string coincides with one in the array.
So, with help of the other answers I made this:

```
var $local_source = [{
        value: 1,
        label: "c++"
    }, {
        value: 2,
        label: "java"
    }, {
        value: 3,
        label: "php"
    }, {
        value: 4,
        label: "coldfusion"
    }, {
        value: 5,
        label: "javascript"
    }, {
        value: 6,
        label: "asp"
    }, {
        value: 7,
        label: "ruby"
    }];
    $('#search-fld').autocomplete({
        source: $local_source,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#search-fld").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $("#search-fldID").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
            return false;
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {

            var isInArray = false;

            $local_source.forEach(function(element, index){

                if ($("#search-fld").val().toUpperCase() == element.label.toUpperCase()) {
                    isInArray = true;
                    $("#search-fld").val(element.label); // display the selected text
                    $("#search-fldID").val(element.value); // save selected id to hidden input
                    console.log('inarray: '+isInArray+' label: '+element.label+' value: '+element.value);
                };

            });

            if(!isInArray){

                $("#search-fld").val(''); // display the selected text
                $( "#search-fldID" ).val( ui.item? ui.item.value : 0 );

            }
        }
```