# How to do a case insensitive search for text within elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, filter, contains, jquery-filter

I have the following basic layout:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div-a">
        <ul id="ul-1">
            <li id="li-1-1" class="li"></li>
            <li id="li-1-2" class="li"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div-b">
        <ul id="ul-2">
            <li id="li-2-2" class="li"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div-c">
        <ul id="ul-3">
            <li id="li-3-1" class="li"></li>
            <li id="li-3-2" class="li"></li>
            <li id="li-3-3" class="li"></li>
            <li id="li-3-4" class="li"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, when an input field gets typed into, it initiates a search of the `<li>` elements. It does a **case insensitive** search on all text contained within the `<li>` elements. The `<li>` element will contain html such as images links paragraphs etc. When a match is found it returns the `<li>` ids e.g. `li-1-1,li-2-1` etc (whatever is best practice). All this is happening while I type. I plan to get the id's and clone the `<li>`. But that shouldn't be important at this stage.

So far I have the following:

```
$('#my-input').keyup(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var keycode = ( e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which );
    if( keycode == 13 ) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        if( $('#my-input').val().length >= 3 ) {

            //code goes here
        }
    }
)}
```

What is the best way to go about this. I have looked at contains, filter, looping over all `.li` elements in various ways etc and had no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

The html part is changed for testing purpose:

```
<input id="my-input"/>
<div id="container">
    <div id="div-a">
        <ul id="ul-1">
            <li id="li-1-1" class="li"><p>This is something wonderful</p></li>
            <li id="li-1-2" class="li"><span>Try is  out</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div-b">
        <ul id="ul-2">
            <li id="li-2-2" class="li"><a href="javascript: void(0)">This needs to be selected</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div-c">
        <ul id="ul-3">
            <li id="li-3-1" class="li">No that wonderful</li>
            <li id="li-3-2" class="li">How is this?</li>
            <li id="li-3-3" class="li">Need to match</li>
            <li id="li-3-4" class="li">No need to match?</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery/JavaScript

$("document").ready(function() {

```
$('#my-input').keyup(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        var matchText = $('#my-input').val();
        if (matchText.length >= 3) {
            var selectedLists = new Array();
            var flagArray = new Array();
            var i = 0;
            $(matchText.split(/\s+/)).each(function() {
                var textToMatch = $(this)[0];
                if (textToMatch && textToMatch != "") {
                    $("li").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).html().match(eval("/" + textToMatch + "/ig"))) {
                            if (!flagArray[$(this).attr("id")]) {
                                selectedLists[i++] = $(this).attr("id"); //For your implementation, I suggest that you store the object, rather than the id so that you can clone it without an iteration
                                flagArray[$(this).attr("id")] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            if (selectedLists.length > 0) {
                alert(selectedLists);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for our time with this. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: Tailored it for my use and it works a treat. My Regex is rubbish but how can I get it to look for all words in the input string. At the moment it looks for precisely what you type in rather than looking for each word in the string.

Comment: Haraldo, I have updated the jQuery part with your requirement. Please have a look at it.