# Need a specific Javascript match regex

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I currently have the following:

```
var sText = 'I like stackoverflow';

if ( $(this).text().match( eval("/" + sText + "/ig") ) ) {
```

As you can see, this matches the entire string.

I need to match case insensitive text that contains all the words individually. So it will look for "I", "like" and "stackoverflow". It must have all 3 words.

Much appreciate the help.

Comment: So you want it to match both `"I like stackoverflow"` and in yoda form, `"stackoverflow I like"` but also string like `"I dont like stackoverflow"`? Question isn't clear

Comment: Yes and "i sTackOverflow Like"!

Comment: instead of eval, you could use RegExp object, which takes two arguments. First is a string (basically regexp, but without the trailing slashes), second is a string of flags ('ig' in your case). On the subject however, if I understood you correctly, `var sText = "(i|like|stackoverflow)";` should do the trick? If it's correct, I'll add is at answer, if it isn't, be more specific.

Comment: Are you attached to RegEx?  Javascript also has a String split method as well.  Maybe I'm not understanding the question though.

Comment: Does it have to match whole words only?

Comment: Zanfa - I've tried that before. I split the sText then join it with "|" e.g. (i|like|stackoverflow) however it still returns true if just stackoverflow is in the string. But I'll test a but more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do this with a match, you can use multiple positive lookahead patterns. For example, to match `a`, `b`, and `c`, in any order:

```
> p = /(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/i

> 'abc'.match(p)
[""]

> 'cba'.match(p)
[""]

> 'ac'.match(p)
null
```

Comment: All i needed was the regex but thanks - you rule. Fixed with: eval("/(?=.*" + aText.join(')(?=.*') + ")/ig"))

Comment: I'd be interested to see this benchmarked for a fairly large value of `sText` especially compared with splitting it into individual regexes per word. I can't be bothered though! This would match `"like Stackoverflow"` btw since it lacks word boundaries, and `like` contains `i`

Answer (score 0):

Why use regular expressions when `.indexOf` will do the job?

```
var str = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
if (str.indexOf('i')>=0 && str.indexOf('like')>=0 && str.indexOf('stackoverflow')>=0) {  
    // ...
}
```

(Mind you, in this case the "i" search is wasted since it's contained in "like", but I assume your actual code is searching for more ordinary text.)

Possible related question: [JavaScript: case-insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/177719/901048)

Comment: The text may be 500 words long(+/-)

Comment: @Haraldo: All the more reason to avoid regular expressions. (Or was that comment meant for another answer?)

Comment: No I was looking at your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split then loop -

```
var sText = 'I like stackoverflow';
var cText = 'stackoverflow like I';
var arr = sText.split(' ');
var match = true;

for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  if (!cText.match(eval("/" + arr[i] + "/ig"))) match= false;
}

alert(match);
```

You'd need to keep efficiency in mind if you were comparing lots of words though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for - the key is the word boundaries.

```
    var text = "text to match"

    var stringToLookFor = "I like stackoverflow";
    var words = stringToLookFor.split(" ");
    var match=true;
    $.each(words, function(index, word) {
        if(!text.match(eval("/\\b" + word + "\\b/i"))) {
            match=false;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/pXz3n/1/)

Comment: I added `return false` which will terminate the loop if a word does not match, yielding improved performance.

Comment: Thanks for your time - I seemed to fix it with Piet Delport's solution.

Comment: @Haraldo does his method give a false positive match on "like stackoverflow"?  Mine does not.