# indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript indexOf case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993773/javascript-indexof-case-insensitive)

how to use IndexOf in javascript to search a key in a string without taking in mind if the key is in lower case or upper case

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var s = "hello world";
 var key="HELLO";
 // the alert should say found if key is lower case or upper case     
 if(s.indexof(key)>1) alert("found") 
 </script>
```

Is their any function in javascript that can check if the key is lower or upper case

Comment: `s.indexof(key)>1` => if key is at the beginning of s, `s.indexof(key)` will return 0. so you should have a -1 instead: `s.indexof(key)>-1`

Comment: let s = "hello world";
let key = "HELLO";
if(s.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) > -1){
Console.log("found");
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both `s` and `key` to lower case using `.toLowerCase()` before using `indexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

look this:

[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_indexof)

this will explain how it works

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `toLowerCase()` function and also check if it is on the first position:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = "hello world";
var key="HELLO";    
if(s.toLowerCase().indexof(key.toLowerCase())>=0) alert("found")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use case-insensitive matching:

```
var string = "This is a HelLo WoRld string";
var lookup = "hellO wOrld";

var result = string.match(lookup,"i");     // "i" = case insensitive
alert(result.index);                       // index starts at 0
```