# Search Through a list By jquery (with case insensitive)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search through the list by search box. This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="query" value=""/>
<ol id="abbreviations" >
<li>Cars</li>
<li>bars</li>
.
.

<ol>
```

And this is the jQuery code I have:

```
<script>

var abbrs = {};

$('ol#abbreviations li').each(function(i){
    abbrs[this.firstChild.nodeValue] = i;
});

$('#query').focus().keyup(function(e){
    if(this.value.length >= 2){
        $('ol#abbreviations li').hide();
        var filterBy = this.value;
        for (var abbr in abbrs) {
            if (abbr.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
               var li = abbrs[abbr];
               $('ol#abbreviations li:eq('+li+')').show();
            }
        }       
    } else {
        $('ol#abbreviations li').show();    
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).val('');
        $('ol#abbreviations li').show();
    }   
});
</script>
```

My code is working perfectly, but it's case sensitive. For example if I type "Cars" it will filter the list, but if I type "cars" it doesn't work. So how can I make this jQuery search insesitive? I tried to changing `var filterBy = this.value.toLowerCase();`, but it won't match upper case letters. How can I make it work?

Comment: You could compare both the list and the value in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) @JakubMichálek +1 , i made it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to lowercase both the `filterValue` and `abbr`:

```
var filterBy = this.value.toLowerCase();
...
if (abbr.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
...
```

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993773/javascript-indexof-case-insensitive)