# How to check if an APEX page item contains a particular substring

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I want to check if a page item contains a substring `ABC`.
I have tried

```
console.log($v("P2_ITEM1").indexOf("ABC"))
```

and it returns `-1` even though the item does contain the substring `ABC`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a betetr way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's right. Are you sure that item contains the string "ABC", indexOf is case sensitive.

I try in this page: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:15:

This instruction and it's ok.

```
console.log($v("P15_SELECT").indexOf("lb"));
console.log($v("P15_SELECTED").indexOf("lb"));
```

[Javascript contains case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993773/javascript-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: how can I replace a value? `apex.item("P2_ITEM1").setValue('');` does not work

Comment: The same, your code is right. Which type of item are P2_ITEM1? In that same test page I execute your code to test apex.item("P15_SELECT").setValue('Albert') and apex.item("P15_SELECTED").setValue('Albert') and works. But if the item is a "select list" you need to set a value that exists in the list.

Comment: P2_ITEM1 is a text field

Comment: Wow, strange, I can't see any error. Other way to set the value is $s("P15_SELECTED","Hello World!"); but using apex_item should work.

Comment: must have been me not selecting "Affected items"