# How to check all possible casing in the string using JS match?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6

`findErr` method should return true if any of the text value in condition found in the string it throws error i added. What would be correct approach to cover all casing scenario ?

```js
const str = "Not Covered Invalid Quantity invalid quantity Invalid quantityfor the product"

const findErrCode = ((item) =>
  item.match(/(Not Covered|Invalid Quantity|invalid quanity|Invalid quantity)/)
);

console.log(findErrCode(str));
```

Error

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
        at findErrCode:43:30
        at eval:46:13
        at eval
        at new Promise
```

Comment: Why are using `item.settlementDesc`? strings don't have a `settlementDesc` property by default.

Comment: Sorry i minimized code for the question i updated question

Comment: The error means that the value of `item` is `undefined`, not a string. The error wouldn't happen in your example though. We cannot you help if you provide an example that doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Doesn't throw the error in the snippet. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @adiga yes i updated the question but i wanted to get boolean value so above code should return true

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions: How to cover different string casing and how to resolve the error. One of them has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8993773/218196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if the string contains either of "Not Covered" or "Invalid Quantity" without caring about their casing, you can use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with an [`i` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters). `i` instructs the `test` to ignore the casing of the string:

```js
const str = "Not Covered Invalid Quantity invalid quantity Invalid quantityfor the product"

const findErrCode = ((item) =>
  /not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(item)
);

console.log(findErrCode("Not Covered Invalid Quantity"));
console.log(findErrCode("InVaLid quAnTity"));
console.log(findErrCode("Valid quantuty"));
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is doing and where are you getting `i` and `test`

Comment: @hussain added links with some explanation

Comment: thank you for the explanation . is there a simple way to implement same code ?

Comment: This is the simple way... it's one of the simplest regular expressions you could use and a basic `.test` method (which simply returns true if the pattern matches and false if not; `.match` will actually try to return the bits that matched, which is slower if you just want to know whether they're there or not).

Answer (score 0):

use Regex after converting the string to lowercase, then you maintain some level of control over the string that is returned.

```
var str = "Not Covered Invalid Quantity INVALID quantityfor the product";

var findErrCode = function()
{
var regex = RegExp("invalid quantity"); 
return regex.test(str.toLowerCase());

}
```

Comment: While a good solution to what the OP wants to do, it doesn't help them resolve the error.

Comment: @JakeSteffen how do we check multiple string can we do this `var regex = RegExp("invalid quantity| Not Covered")`

Comment: @JakeSteffen message could contain Not Covered or Invalid Quantity

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean try this js bin: https://jsbin.com/doforonico/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @JakeSteffen what if string does not have invalid quantity it has Not Covered that should also considered to be omit