# Make an array case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, case-insensitive

I am trying to remove a div that contains specific words.

Here's the sample jquery code:

```
var someArray = [
        'someword',
        'someword2',
        'someword3'
  ];

    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        $("div:contains('"+someArray[i]+"').remove();
  }
```

Only the divs including the word "someword" is removed, but not "Someword, SOMEWORD, soMeWoRd" etc.

How do I make the array case insentisive matching both combinations?

Comment: hi/selam soner, This question may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search

Comment: This saved me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8
Sorry for duplicate.