# search case insensitive letters in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, case-insensitive

I am trying to search the contents using jquery. Search option working fine. But, I have faced some case insensitive problem here. My full codes on jsfiddle. if i put senthil in my search it didn't show the result. Because, I have Senthil (Uppercase S) in my content. How do I find Uppercase letters in jquery?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/31/)

```
$('#search').on('input', function(){
                var text = $(this).val();
                $('.subjects a').show();    
                $('.subjects a:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
                $('.subjects a span').show();
            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: case-insensitive search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom expression for `contains` like this:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/32/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your JS code

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Credits [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/)