# indexOf return -1 with the correct string JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, indexof

I have an `ul` with `li` inside. So I use `$.each()` to search each `id` of `li`.

My problem is, I've an `id` that's "Nouvelle AC". But when I use `$(product).indexOf("NOUVELLE");` It returns -1.

To figure out it and turn more easy to understand, I created an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99mJC/1/).
Use console to understand what I said.

**The HTML**:

```
<ul class="product-list">
    <li class="product" id="Me too AC"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Wish BR"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Nouvelle AC"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Gloss Pearl AC"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Gloss Pearl BR"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Kish too AC"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Kit Wish BR"></li>
    <li class="product" id="Fresh AC"></li>
</ul>
```

**The JS**:

```
$('ul.product-list li.product').each(function() {
    var product = "NOUVELLE";
    var produtoloaded = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Product loaded: '+produtoloaded);
    console.log('Product searched: '+product);
    console.log('If contains: '+produtoloaded.indexOf(product));

    if (produtoloaded.indexOf(product) > -1) {
        //IF INDEX IS MORE THAN -1 THE STRING CONTAINS THE PRODUCT
        var offsetTop = produtoloaded.offsetTop;
        console.log(offsetTop);
    }
});
```

Comment: case sensitivity http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/V4WMZ/. Use `produtoloaded.toUpperCase().indexOf(product.toUpperCase())`

Comment: You are finding the indexOf product in id values of li which does not exists.

Comment: you can't write "var product = "Nouvelle";" ?

Comment: The ID Exists. Please try again. You'll see "Nouvelle AC" in LI's

Comment: @FrédéricGRATI I can't. Because this is just to figure out, in my code it comes from PHP.

Comment: You might want to use [case insensitive matching.][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of exact search... `indexOf` function looks for exact string, it is case sensitive:

```
var product = "NOUVELLE"; //or make in lower case already so that you can skip 'product= product.toLowerCase();'
var produtoloaded = $(this).attr('id');
product = product.toLowerCase();
produtoloaded = produtoloaded.toLowerCase();

console.log('Product loaded: '+produtoloaded);
console.log('Product searched: '+product);
console.log('If contains: '+produtoloaded.indexOf(product));

if (produtoloaded.indexOf(product) > -1) {
    //IF INDEX IS MORE THAN -1 THE STRING CONTAINS THE PRODUCT
    var offsetTop = produtoloaded.offsetTop;
    console.log(offsetTop);
}
```

You can call in Upper case also, just call `toUpperCase()` instead of `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for uppercase characters in a string which is not.

Add .toUpperCase() and it will work.

```
produtoloaded.toUpperCase().indexOf(product)
```

Even better would be to do both strings to upper or lowercase, this will prevent typo's messing up the logic.

```
produtoloaded.toUpperCase().indexOf(product.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is case sensitivity:

```
var product = "NOUVELLE";
var produtoloaded = $(this).attr('id');
product = product.toLowerCase();
produtoloaded = produtoloaded.toLowerCase();
```

[MDN Doc : `.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)