# Regex, how do I say, match everything but one word?

Tags: javascript, regex, iis

Using regex I'm trying to match anything BUT one word, that word being '/item/'.

```
([^/]+)
```

That matches anything (true), but I'd like it to be false if the word '/item/' is in there.

Would I have to do something like this?

```
([^/]+|!/item/)
```

Where the pipe is 'OR' and the ! is 'is not,' this example that I've written is definitely the wrong syntax... I'm a newb when it comes to regex.

**Update:**

Here is the live example:

```
^(category)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

category/all-weather-wicker/bermuda/**table**/2977/ *should pass*

category/all-weather-wicker/bermuda/**item**/2977/ *should fail*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i think the pipe should mean and...otherwise you want (anything or anything not item) which is anything

Comment: Why not just check if the word 'item' is in the string? `str.indexOf("item");` returns -1 if it's not present, otherwhise it returns a positive number.

Comment: Building on what @Michel said, check out the second example of the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search

It doesn't require regular expressions and it wont require sanitizing user input to exclude metacharacters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings will always be consistent, you could use a **Negative Lookahead** here.

```
^(category)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/((?:(?!\bitem\b).)+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pK4oV1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var subject = "category/all-weather-wicker/bermuda/item/bermuda-end-table/table/2977/";
if (/^category(?!.*?\/item\/\d+\/).*?$/im.test(subject)) {
    console.log("passed");
} else {
    console.log("failed");
}
```

***<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4thLk/4/)</kbd>***

***EXPLANATION:***

```
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «^»
Match the character string “category” literally (case insensitive) «category»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!.*?/item/\d+/)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character string “/item/” literally (case insensitive) «/item/»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator) «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «$»
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the reverse logic, might be easier to look for the existance of '/item/'

javascript...

```
var st1 = 'here is a string with /item/ in it';
var m = st1.match(/\/\bitem\b\//g);
m = (m !== null)?false:true;
console.log(m);
```

NOTE: don't forget to escape your "/" like "\/"

here is a fiddle to demonstrate...

http://jsfiddle.net/KF4De/