# Javascript: multiple expressions in array when searching strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm currently working with Javascript and for now I'm searching a way to check if variable contains at least one string. I have looked at previous questions, however, neither contain what I'm looking for. I have a function here:

```
function findCertainWords() 
{
    var t = {Some text value};
    if (t in {'one':'', 'two':''}) 
       return alert("At least one string is found. Change them."), 0;
    return 1
}
```

Variable a is user's written text (for example, a comment or a post).

I want to check if user has written certain word in it and return an alert message to remove/edit that word. While my written function works, it only works when user writes that word exactly as I write in my variable (`"Three" != "three"`). I want to improve my funtion so it would also find case-insensitive (`"Three" == "three"`) and part of words (like "thr" from "three"). I tried to put an expression like `*` but it didn't work.

It would be the best if every expression could be written in one function. Otherwise, I might need help with combining two functions.

Comment: Have you considered using `toLowerString`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: see this link i hope it will help you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search

Comment: `t.match(/(one|two)/i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to test if a string contains another string. Use `.toLowerCase` to convert it to one case before comparing.

```
function findCertainWords(t) {
    var words = ['one', 'two'];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (t.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) != -1) {
            alert("At least one string was found. Change them.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another way is to turn the array into a regexp:

```
    var regexp = new RegExp(words.join('|'));
    if (regexp.test(t)) {
        alert("At least one string was found. Change them.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.some` with `Object.keys`

```
if(Object.keys(obj).some(function(k){
   return ~a.indexOf(obj[k]);
})){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You need to compare `indexOf` with `-1`. How does `~~` turn it into a boolean?

Comment: I intended to use `~`

Comment: Why add `*` to the key when creating the regexp? That means the last character of the key can appear zero or more times. So it will match if the last character is missing.