# How do I make an case-insensitive search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$("#input").keyup(function () {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    $("#list div").map(function (index, value) {
        $(value).toggle($(value).text().toString().indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
    });
});
```

here is the code

How do I make it case insensitive? is it possible? I tried using `css` to force lowercase on user input but did not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: case-insensitive search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var userInputLower = userInput.toLowerCase();
var shouldToggle = $(value).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userInputLower) >= 0;
$(value).toggle(shouldToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.toLowerCase()`

```
"HELLOOOooo".toLowerCase(); // hellooooo
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind case insensitive searches it to convert both the source (string to look for) as well as the target (strings that are compared to the source) to lowercase.
Then both have the same casing, which makes it case insensitive.
Converting both the source and target strings to uppercase will give the same result, but to lowercase is used most often.