# is there an easy was to make all string compares in a js file case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to make all string compares in a js file case-insensitive?  Here's a simple example of a normal check:

```
var message = 'This is a Test';
var isTest = message.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') > -1;
```

This isn't a bad approach for a single check but it gets verbose if it needs to be done 10+ times in a file.  Is there an easier way to make string compares case-insensitive for the entire scope of a js file?

Comment: wrap it in a function, and then call the function throughout your file.

Comment: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) can make case-insensitive test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: case-insensitive search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own function and use that everywhere.

```js
function contains(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().indexOf(b.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

console.log(contains('This is a Test', 'test'));
console.log(contains('ABC', 'abc'));
console.log(contains('ABCdefGHI', 'Fgh'));
console.log(contains('Nope, no match', 'See?'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1- Regex with `i` to make it case-insensitive

```
/test/i.test(message)
```

2- Make a function that does that, with the possibility of assigning it to the `String` object

```
// wrapper function
function iIncludes(needle, haystack) {
  return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) >= 0;
}
iIncludes('test', 'This is a Test') // returns true

// attached to the String prototype
if (!String.prototype.iIncludes) {
  String.prototype.iIncludes = function(needle) {
    return this.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) >= 0;
  }
}
'This is a Test'.iIncludes('test') // returns true
```

As an aside, if you can use ES6 features (not compatible with all browsers), there's a "better" method than `indexOf`, see [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)