# How to compare two strings regardless of their capitalization?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
mytext = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
```

then I do

```
if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text() == mytext) {
```

But one title could be:

`Space Mission` just as well as `space mission`

I cannot standardise the text format for other reasons therefore I am really looking at comparing two strings regardless of their capitalisation.

**UPDATE**

The thing is that I am using the input field as a search so the user could type `space mission` while the post title would be `Space mission` so the search result wouldn't be exact and i need the exact phrase instead.

Complete code:

```
<div id="datafetch"></div>

function fetch(){
  jQuery('#datafetch').empty();
  mytext = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  mytext },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text().toLowerCase().trim() == mytext.toLowerCase().trim()) {
            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
        } else {
                jQuery("#componi").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").show();
        }
            if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text() != mytext) {
            jQuery("#fatto").hide();
            jQuery('#datafetch').empty();
        }
        }
    });

}
```

It's trickier actually because the search is coming from the text input, so it's about the query of the ajax i believe more than capitalisation, just a thought. The latest code above gives no results by typing:

`space mission` while the post title is `Space mission`

**UPDATE 2**

Post article title:

```
Space Mission
```

User searches for

```
space mission
```

Console.log(data) gives correct result

```
   <ul class="list-unstyled margin-top-80">
       <li>
            <h2><a target="_blank" href="example.com"">Space Mission</a></h2>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

Yet this doesn't happens:

```
jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
```

if I insert the right words `Space Mission` does tho

Comment: `String#toLowerCase` does not work for you?

Comment: @NinaScholz update the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: case-insensitive search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)

Comment: please add some use cases to make clear, what you want.

Comment: it looks more like a ajax question, than a string problem. does it work with the exact input and search?

Comment: yes exactly what I thought, it does work indeed with the exact words...

Comment: @rob.m can you share what exact `data` comes back as ajax response?

Comment: you just completely changed the whole context of the question. Is there possibility for more than one `<a>` in the response that needs to be checked also?

Comment: and why isn't this validation done server side?

Comment: @gurvinder372 i just checked the console.log for data and it is actually getting the correct data so it is a comparison problem still

Comment: @charlietfl see above comment. Also it is done server side because it's a wizard and I don't want people to create articles with the same title, so i am doing a check first

Comment: @rob.m can you update your question to post what exact `data` comes back, and what exactly has been entered by user?

Comment: last comment doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of checking this html that is sent from server where you already know if there is a match or not

Comment: @gurvinder372 sure, just did it see the update

Comment: @charlietfl see if the updated question helps you and forget about the server side for now.

Comment: `jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );` is not dependent on anything the way question code is shown....other then the response data and a matching selector element. Symptom of `doesn't happen` doesn't make sense unless `jQuery('#datafetch')` doesn't exist

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean sorry? data will have to be placed into <div id="datafetch"></div>

Comment: right but your update says it doesn't get inserted if query doesn't match but there is no dependency for inserting the html. This is turning into an XY Problem

Comment: @charlietfl and it doesn't. I can see it only in console.log(data) for some reasons but it doesn't get appended

Comment: well the way the code is shown there is nothing preventing it being inserted and problem is eleshwere or code shown is not what is being used

Comment: it is indeed the same...

Comment: Then create a demo that reproduces this problem. Can do ajax in many of the sandbox sites like plunker, jsfiddle etc

Comment: @charlietfl ok the issue is with the else if, if you see above i am doing first else and the a separate if. SO it is kinda wrong the code above. however while adjusting it on here, i noticed that this is never happens if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text() != mytext) {

Comment: @gurvinder372 accepted yours as it was correct but check my own answer

Comment: @charlietfl the comparison was still needed and the accepted answer is correct but check my own answer for the final solution

Comment: doesn't explain *"Yet this doesn't happens:"* part of question though which implies that the html doesn't get inserted at all when the terms don't match. That statement is misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is correct and it does answer my original question, and that's why I accepted it. However, the issue was solved by using a `setTimeout(function()` as there was a little delay between the data populating the div and the check for the 2 value comparisons.

```
function fetch(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  jQuery('#usp-title').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                    jQuery("#datafetch").html(data);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var text1 = jQuery("#datafetch").find("h2").find("a").html();
                        var text1B = text1.toLowerCase();
                        var text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
                        var text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
                        if(text1B == text2B) {
                            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
                        } else {
                            jQuery("#componi").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").show();
                            jQuery("#fatto").hide();
                            jQuery('#datafetch').empty();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
            }
        });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using `.promise().done()` was better

```
function fetch(){
    var text1;
    var text1B;
    var text2;
    var text2B;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  jQuery('#usp-title').val() },
            success: function(data) {
                    jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function(){
                        text1 = jQuery("#datafetch").find("h2").find("a").html();
                        text1B = text1.toLowerCase();
                        text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
                        text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
                        if (text1B != text2B) {
                            jQuery("#componi").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").show();
                            jQuery("#fatto").hide();
                            jQuery('#datafetch').empty();
                        } else if (text1B == text2B) {
                            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

**UPDATE TWO**

This is what I finally used

```
function fetch(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  jQuery('#usp-title').val() },
    success: function(data) {
      var text2;
      var text2B;
      text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
      text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
      jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function(){
        jQuery("#datafetch ul li h2 a").each(function() {
          var $this = jQuery(this);
          if ($this.text().toLowerCase() !== text2B) {
            $this.parent().parent().hide();
          } else if (text1B == text2B) {
            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: no need for setTimeout if you just wrap the response in `$()` and work inside that

Comment: @charlietfl i resolved it by using .promise().done and i have updated this answer

Answer (score 8):

Covert both `toLowercase()`

```
"Space Mission".toLowerCase() == "space mission".toLowerCase()
```

In context of your question

```
if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text().toLowerCase() == mytext.toLowerCase()) {
```

Trimming in case user enters trailing or leading space, as suggested by @charlietfl

```
if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text().trim().toLowerCase() == mytext.trim().toLowerCase()) {
```

Comment: this is ok, was trying it, thanks. I have update the question, my fault as i wasn't too clear about.

Comment: might also want to trim them for safety

Comment: yeah but then you will search for a title like spacemission and there isn't any title like that

Comment: @rob.m trimming only removes whitespace on the ends, not between characters

Comment: @rob.m user may not enter `spacemission` but can enter `" space mission "`, so provisioning for leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: also could be whitespace in html, not just user input

Comment: this answer does not match the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am not sure about that. Based on the `data` OP has shared, this could be the only thing OP could be missing to make it work.

Comment: it does not match, because the question is disputed. as long as the question is unclear, **any** answers are just tries and not answers.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think it does. I started having my own doubts when OP and you made some comments which was more around AJAX rather than string match. But the doubt got cleared when OP shared the `data` which made it clear that this could be the only thing OP is missing, unless there are some things which OP hasn't shared. Let's agree to disagree on `as long as the question is unclear, any answers are just tries and not answers`

Comment: @NinaScholz see my own answer

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks a lot, the issue was somewhere else yet your answer helped and it is correct.

Comment: @rob.m I am not sure why `setTimeout` is required since `.html` method is not asynchronous

Comment: @gurvinder372 seriously, at this point i don't know anymore. If I don't do that it won't work thats' for sure

Comment: @gurvinder372 guess what, using promise and done was even better jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function(){ - updated my answer too

Answer (score 1):

Get the input result using jquery

```
var string = jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text()
```

and then you can try any of the following -

**Simple string comparison** : converting both to same case :

```
string.toUpperCase() === "String".toUpperCase()
```

**If you are fine with regex**(notice the i option in regex) :

```
var otherString = /String/i
otherString.test(string)
```

**There is "match" as well :**

```
string.match(/STRING/i)
```

match returns null value when no match found

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
"Space Mission".replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase() == "space    mission".replace(/\s+/g, "").toLowerCase()
```

The left hand side will be equal to `spacemission` same as the expression on the right sade

It will first remove any white space even in between words & will convert to lower case. Removing white space is necessary because `space    mission` is not same as `space mission`

Comment: yeah but then you will search for a title like spacemission and there isn't any title like that

Answer (score 0):

You will require to convert both strings to lowercase or uppercase and then do the comparison.

```
    var mytext = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
    if(jQuery("#datafetch h2 a").text().toLowerCase() == mytext.toLowerCase()) 
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both strings to upper or lower case